# Error 'EMFILE: too many open files, open' VSTS in Release

Tags: angular, azure, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-deployment

I am trying to deploy the Angular 5 sample Heros App to Azure using Azure's Continous Delivery, it is failing on the release with the following error:

```
2018-01-14T13:22:41.8301597Z ##[section]Starting: Deploy Azure App Service
2018-01-14T13:22:41.8501466Z ==============================================================================
2018-01-14T13:22:41.8501809Z Task         : Azure App Service Deploy
2018-01-14T13:22:41.8502244Z Description  : Update Azure WebApp Services On Windows, Web App On Linux with built-in images or docker containers, ASP.NET, .NET Core, PHP, Python or Node based Web applications, Function Apps, Mobile Apps, Api applications, Web Jobs using Web Deploy / Kudu REST APIs
2018-01-14T13:22:41.8502677Z Version      : 3.3.32
2018-01-14T13:22:41.8502922Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-01-14T13:22:41.8503185Z Help         : [More Information](https://aka.ms/azurermwebdeployreadme)
2018-01-14T13:22:41.8504109Z ==============================================================================
2018-01-14T13:22:46.1519999Z Got connection details for Azure App Service:'herotest'
2018-01-14T13:23:27.5420784Z ##[error]Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'd:\a\r1\a\temp_web_package_029438318867875735\node_modules\webdriver-js-extender\built\spec\command_tests\normal_spec.d.ts'
2018-01-14T13:23:33.6581680Z Successfully updated deployment History at https://herotest.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/11515936207535
2018-01-14T13:23:35.9365916Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy Azure App Service
```

The code I am trying to deploy is https://github.com/dragsdale75/hero

I previously deployed the basic app by following this tutorial, but it was simpler.
https://passos.com.au/build-and-deploy-an-angular-app-from-github-to-azure-website/

The changes made to the Angular Heros App, included adding a kuduscript, modifying the script and adding 2 dependencies.

[image: Azure Continous Delivery]

Since the build was successful, I don't feel like this is an Angular issue. However, the hero apps example is not on the most recent version of the CLI.

I don't know what additional information would assist, here is the only step in the VSTS release.  It was assembled by the Azure CI tool.

[image: Deploy Azure App Service options]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you configured Continuous Delivery with Node.js web application framework and None task runner in Azure, and the build tasks are: 1. Npm install 2. Archive files 3. Copy Files 4. Publish Build Artifacts.

With these task, it won’t build the app and you upload all the source code files to app service, which don’t work for your scenario.

To deal with this issue, you can add npm task (Step 2) to build your app and just publish output files to Artifact (Step 3: Change folder path) and upload to app service:

1. Npm install task
2. Npm task (Command: `custom`; Working folder with package.json: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`; Command and arguments: `run build`
3. Archive Files (Root folder to archive: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/dist`)
4. Copy Files
5. Publish Build Artifacts